# xib loads with iPhone size on iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a nib file where autolayout is configured to layout the view correctly on both iPad and iPhone.

When the nib loads, the size is incorrectly set to 320 on the iPad. I log the width in both init (after calling super initWithNibName) and also viewDidLoad. The width is 320 in both places.

The superview fills the entire screen.

I'd rather not maintain two nib files for iPhone and iPad.

Any idea why my nib isn't expanding properly?

Comment: You have not properly set the Autolayout masks. Have you checked these?

Comment: I'm using autolayout so I don't believe auto-resizing masks are used. I did ensure autolayout is configured to expand the view to the size of it's parent.

Comment: Some of the constraints in autolayout should be wrong. Can you post a screenshot with the constraints of your xib? Or code if you add them programmatically?